# WordPress 5.7.2 missing a temporary folder error with new media files

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media, temporary-files

I have migrated several wordpress sites to a dev server to test before upgrading.  All seems to be working except I cannot upload new image files.  I have tried/checked the following:

- permissions have been granted to the `wp-content` folder
- there is a `tmp` and `temp` folder in `wp-content`
- I have a `php.ini` file with this code: `upload_tmp_dir=/home/username/public_html/temp`
- I have added these snippets to my wp-config file:

```
 define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/'.'uploads');
 define('WP_TEMP_DIR', dirname(_FILE_). '/wp-content/temp/');
```

- I have disabled plug-ins and tried other themes

Migrated images are there and working. I just can't add new ones.

I am using the MH NewsDesk Lite Theme, WP 5.7.2v on IIS 10.  We host everything internally so I have no hosting company to investigate.  And I have run out of ideas.  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Is the WordPress site installed in the root folder or a subfolder?

Comment: It is installed in the root folder

Comment: Check for any error logs.

Comment: I found this error.  [17-Sep-2021 12:45:04 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  has_cap was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version 2.0.0! Usage of user levels is deprecated. Use capabilities instead. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5145

Comment: So I have solved the mystery and it's quite a doozy.  Along the way the came across some to things to check if you are having trouble.  Here are some other things to check along the way.   1- Try these in your wp-config file -define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' ); and -define('WP_TEMP_DIR', sys_get_temp_dir());   2 - check the php.ini file in your PHP folder to see if the needed extensions are uncommented like the extension=gd2.  If you are on V8 then it has changed to extension=gd.

Comment: But ultimately the problem was 3 - since my sites are running on IIS 10, this issue was confusion b/t the Windows temp folder and the WordPress temp folder. If you do not set the upload_tmp_dir path then files get saved to the Windows temp folder and when the files are copied by WordPress the Windows temp permissions are applied instead of the WordPress permissions. So I set the upload_tmp_dir path in the php.ini to C:\wpupload then made a wpupload folder on C and gave it IUSR R,W,E rights. Then it worked.